# Adding a link into an existing td

Tags: jquery

I have a table with four columns.  I'm adding rows to the table dynamically with jquery and in the fourth column is a "Delete" link.  I need to remove the link from the row when a new row is added.  This is all happening and working as I want it too.  The problem comes when I want to delete the row.  I need to put the delete link back on the previous row in the existing td, the issue I have is that a new td is being created and the link being placed into it.  This is the code

```
function RemoveUnsavedTier() {
    $('#TierDetails tr:last').remove();
    $('#TierDetails tr:last td:last').after("<a href='#' id='RemoveTier'>Delete tier</a>");
}
```

I know it's because I'm using `after` but I don't know what I should be using instead.

Comment: user append instead of after                           $('#TierDetails tr:last td:last').append("<a href='#' id='RemoveTier'>Delete tier</a>");

Comment: @Chinmayee, please add your solution as an answer so that Simon is able to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

user append instead of after

```
$('#TierDetails tr:last td:last').append("<a href='#' id='RemoveTier'>Delete tier</a>");
```